# How to write udev rule to make /dev/sdX readonly?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition, udev

I am very often dealing with formatting usb drives, that are registered as /dev/sdX. Accidentally, I may mistype the command, and format my harddrive.

I think ideally I would want to write I think an UDEV rule to make specific /dev/sdX drivers readonly, including all the /dev/sdX* and at best also all the `/dev/disc/by-*/*`. This would make any `dd of=/dev/sdX` and `fdisk /dev/sdX` and `mkfs /dev/sdX` fail. Then, if I really want to modify, at any time I can just `chmod +w`.

How would such an UDEV rule look like? How to get some information about /dev/sdX path so to "match" it with an UDEV rule? How to match all /dev/sdX* partitions?

```
# smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 7.3 2022-02-28 r5338 [x86_64-linux-6.2.2-zen2-1-zen] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-22, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Green
Device Model:     WDC WD6400AAVS-00G9B1
Serial Number:    WD-WCAUF2886253
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 202989df7
Firmware Version: 05.04C05
User Capacity:    640,135,028,736 bytes [640 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5319
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 12 05:46:50 2023 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

```
# udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk --path=block/sda | cat

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata6/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sda':
    KERNEL=="sda"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{capability}=="0"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{diskseq}=="1"
    ATTR{events}==""
    ATTR{events_async}==""
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{hidden}=="0"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{integrity/device_is_integrity_capable}=="0"
    ATTR{integrity/format}=="none"
    ATTR{integrity/protection_interval_bytes}=="0"
    ATTR{integrity/read_verify}=="0"
    ATTR{integrity/tag_size}=="0"
    ATTR{integrity/write_generate}=="0"
    ATTR{mq/0/cpu_list}=="0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7"
    ATTR{mq/0/nr_reserved_tags}=="0"
    ATTR{mq/0/nr_tags}=="32"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/add_random}=="1"
    ATTR{queue/chunk_sectors}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/dax}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/discard_granularity}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/discard_max_bytes}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/discard_max_hw_bytes}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/discard_zeroes_data}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/dma_alignment}=="511"
    ATTR{queue/fua}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/hw_sector_size}=="512"
    ATTR{queue/io_poll}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/io_poll_delay}=="-1"
    ATTR{queue/io_timeout}=="30000"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/back_seek_max}=="16384"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/back_seek_penalty}=="2"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/fifo_expire_async}=="250"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/fifo_expire_sync}=="125"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/low_latency}=="1"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/max_budget}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/slice_idle}=="8"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/slice_idle_us}=="8000"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/strict_guarantees}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/iosched/timeout_sync}=="125"
    ATTR{queue/iostats}=="1"
    ATTR{queue/logical_block_size}=="512"
    ATTR{queue/max_discard_segments}=="1"
    ATTR{queue/max_hw_sectors_kb}=="32767"
    ATTR{queue/max_integrity_segments}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/max_sectors_kb}=="1280"
    ATTR{queue/max_segment_size}=="65536"
    ATTR{queue/max_segments}=="168"
    ATTR{queue/minimum_io_size}=="512"
    ATTR{queue/nomerges}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/nr_requests}=="64"
    ATTR{queue/nr_zones}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/optimal_io_size}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/physical_block_size}=="512"
    ATTR{queue/read_ahead_kb}=="128"
    ATTR{queue/rotational}=="1"
    ATTR{queue/rq_affinity}=="1"
    ATTR{queue/scheduler}=="none mq-deadline kyber [bfq] "
    ATTR{queue/stable_writes}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/throttle_sample_time}=="100"
    ATTR{queue/virt_boundary_mask}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/write_cache}=="write back"
    ATTR{queue/write_same_max_bytes}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/write_zeroes_max_bytes}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/zone_append_max_bytes}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/zone_write_granularity}=="0"
    ATTR{queue/zoned}=="none"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{removable}=="0"
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="1250263728"
    ATTR{stat}=="     355        0    21348     2856        8        0        0       18        0     1424     2893        0        0        0        0        8       18"
    ATTR{trace/act_mask}=="disabled"
    ATTR{trace/enable}=="0"
    ATTR{trace/end_lba}=="disabled"
    ATTR{trace/pid}=="disabled"
    ATTR{trace/start_lba}=="disabled"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata6/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="5:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{blacklist}==""
    ATTRS{delete}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{inquiry}==""
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x1c1"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x24"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x1c1"
    ATTRS{iotmo_cnt}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{model}=="WDC WD6400AAVS-0"
    ATTRS{ncq_prio_enable}=="0"
    ATTRS{ncq_prio_supported}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="741934"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="32"
    ATTRS{queue_ramp_up_period}=="120000"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="simple"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rev}=="4C05"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="6"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="ATA     "
    ATTRS{vpd_pg0}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pg80}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pg83}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pg89}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pgb0}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pgb1}==""
    ATTRS{vpd_pgb2}==""
    ATTRS{wwid}=="naa.50014ee202989df7"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata6/host5/target5:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target5:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="741935"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata6/host5':
    KERNELS=="host5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="741936"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="314"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata6':
    KERNELS=="ata6"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="742252"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1f.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ahci"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x010601"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e02"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="28"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/28}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="742302"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{remapped_nvme}=="0"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset_method}=="af_flr"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x04"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x11d6"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1734"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

Comment: Block devices normally belong to the root user, root can do anything to them regardless.

Comment: I see that I have not tested that enough. Doing `chmod ugo-w /dev/sdc1` and then `mkfs /dev/sdc1` still allows to partition the disc. Is there any way I can "lock" /dev/sdc1 to be readonly and disallow partitioning? Making the /dev/sdc readonly seemed like a solution.

Comment: I am asking  here 2 questions. Let me fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the udev rules for it is relatively simple. Just add the following to `/etc/udev/rules.d/yourname.rule`:

```
ATTRS{wwid}=="naa.50014ee202989df7", MODE="0440"
```

Here I used `wwid` present in the output of `udevadm info --query=all --attribute-walk --path=/sys/block/sda` to unique match the disc. You can repeat this for any disc.

Note that this will **not** protect against `mkfs /dev/sda1`. `mkfs` seems to be unaffected even when `/dev/sda1` has `0000` permissions.